# build-tool: [0x0003] How should we publish a project which has a dependency in some local or flatDir?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, repository

> I do have a few local artifacts(compiled) some do not have a POM file or any other metadata, I would like to depend on it to my current project and in the end publish this project. The problem is the "publications(maven/ivy/...)" needed a concrete notations on this artifact before you could publish it. But this kind of artifacts didn't have a version concatenating on it neither any metadata. I did some research on my own and finally it has been published but in the consumer side it cannot resolve?

```
//: library-demo/build.gradle.kts

 repositories {
    flatDir {
        setDirs(listOf(System.getProperty("url.repo.external.flatdir.release")))
    }
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:3.2.3"))
    listOf(
        "", "-assimp", "-openal",
        "-opengl" ).map { lib ->
            implementation(":lwjgl$lib")
            runtimeOnly(":lwjgl$lib${LWJGL.lwjglNatives}")
        }
}


publishing {
    publications {
        register<MavenPublication>("library-demo-maven") {
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            setUrl(System.getProperty("url.repo.local.snapshot"))
        }
    }
}
```

> the consumer build script, and inside of dependency block found an error, in this specific binary cannot resolve. How do we fix this broken metadata?

```
//: other-library/build.gradle.kts
repositories {
    maven {
        setUrl(System.getProperty("url.repo.local.snapshot"))
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation("com.demo:library-demo:0.0.1") // HERE: ERROR cannot found this binary!
}
```

Comment: Either copy them in or do publish them.

Comment: @chrylis..., um ok, some **local artifacts** I have in here are _published_ by a third party domain and **it did not have any metadata**, is there a way to give them some useful **matadata** via _Gradle_? for example the _LWJGL zip file_ containing minimalistic **artifacts** that **did not have any metadata**.